# Longitudinal modelling of ordinal censored data

Tags: r, mixed-model

I have n subjects observed over some time $t{\scriptscriptstyle n}<T$ . At several time points during $T$, I measure in each subject the value of an ordinal variable $V$ (which can take 5 values). Not every subject has measurements in every time point and there is censoring of the subjects during T.

I would like to model the probability of a random subject being in each of the categories of V over time, allowing for a random subject effect.

What would be the most appropriate methods to perform this? Is it possible in R and could someone pinpoint me to any information sources about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Th R package 'msm' by Christopher Jackson is entitled "Multi-state Markov and hidden Markov models in continuous time" and provides for the censoring as well as estimating transition probabilities between ordered states over time. Some treatment of covariate effectts is offered although I cannot tell if it meets you constraint for being "random subject effects". I do not see any methods for imputing missing values, so that would need to be handled as a separate process.